# Can any one help me to link uploaded DICOM image to the modality worklist patient?

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

I am uploading image using the storescu dcm4chee utility, but when image is uploaded I am not able to link that image to the patient which contains the radiology order created from the bahmni.

Please help me to know the flow that how modality links the image to the patients and what to do for linking that image to the patient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to identify the study:

- Study Instance UID (0020,000D) - if provided by Modality Work list Service
- Accession number (0008,0050)
- Requested Procedure ID (0040,1001)

You can use Following to identify the patient:

- Patient ID (0010,0020)
- Patient's Name (0010,0010)
- Patient's Birth Date (0010, 0030)
- Patient's Sex (0010, 0040)